# Split table with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery plugin that will let me split a table into multiple tables. I need to be able to split tables into 2, 3 and 4 new tables.

I was able to produce code that works as expected on most browsers, but it fails in IE 10.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.splitTable = function(options) {

    // Options
    var settings = $.extend({
      tableSplit: 2,
    }, options);

    var tbl = this,
      tblHead = tbl.children('thead'),
      tblBody = tbl.children('tbody');

    if (tbl.is('table')) {
      tbl.html('<div class="js-split-table-container js-split-table-container-' +
          settings.tableSplit + '" />')
        .children().unwrap()
        .each(function() {

          var rowsPerTable = [],
            rows = tblBody.children('tr'),
            minRowsPerTable = Math.floor(rows.length / settings.tableSplit),
            difference = rows.length - (minRowsPerTable * settings.tableSplit);

          for (var i = 0; i < settings.tableSplit; i++) {
            if (i < difference) {
              rowsPerTable[i] = minRowsPerTable + 1;
            } else {
              rowsPerTable[i] = minRowsPerTable;
            }
          }

          for (i = 0; i < settings.tableSplit; i++) {
            $('<table class="js-split-table js-split-table-' + (i + 1) + '"><tbody /></table>')
              .prepend(tblHead.clone())
              .appendTo($(this))
              .wrap('<div class="js-split-table-item js-split-table-item-' + (i + 1) + '" />');
            for (var j = 0; j < rowsPerTable[i]; j++) {
              var pointer = 0;
              for (var k = 0; k < i; k++) {
                pointer += rowsPerTable[k];
              }
              $(this).find('.js-split-table-' + (i + 1) + ' tbody')
                .append(rows[j + pointer]);
            }
          }
        });
    }
  };
}(jQuery));

$('table').splitTable({
  tableSplit: 3
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: I am not seeing any errors in the console in any browser.

Comment: `tbl.html('<div>...')` looks wrong. You can't put a DIV directly in a TABLE.

Comment: Yes, the next line selects the div and unwraps it. So the outer table is removed.

Comment: I suspect IE10 doesn't like it when you put the DIV into the TABLE. It doesn't know you're going to unwrap it in the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this working with this revised code. Works in IE and all other browsers.

```js
function splitTable(tableCount, table){
 var splitTables = $('<div class="js-split-table-container js-split-table-' + tableCount + '" />'),
  thead = table.children('thead'),
  tbody = table.children('tbody'),
  rowCount = tbody.children('tr').length,
  tableRows = Math.floor(rowCount / tableCount),
  difference = rowCount - (tableRows * tableCount);

 for (var i=0; i < tableCount; i++) {
  if(i < difference) {
   rowsPerTable = tableRows + 1;
  } else {
   rowsPerTable = tableRows;
  }
  var rows = tbody.children('tr').slice(0, rowsPerTable),
   newTables = $('<table class="js-split-table-item js-split-table-item' + (i + 1) + ' "><tbody /></table>')
    .append(rows)
    .prepend(thead.clone());
  splitTables.append(newTables);
  rowsPerTable = tableRows;
 }
 table.replaceWith(splitTables);
}
splitTable(3, $("table.split-table"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="split-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Blah Blah</td>
      <td>2016</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```